# Nested routing in Angular with wildcards on different route levels

Tags: angular, angular-router

I have a website with two nested `<router-outlet>` elements. The main outlet can show several different pages with lists mostly differing in their call to the database, so instead of creating several components with ultimately the same content, I created one that takes a *type* argument from the url and bases the database request on that argument.
However, if someone calls a url that does not exist on the main level, or provides an incorrect type argument, they're supposed to be redirected to an error page inside of the main outlet.

If someone clicks on an item in the list, an edit page is supposed to open inside of the child outlet, with another argument, the item's *id*, which is now used together with the parent's *type* argument for another database call. If someone calls an incorrect child route or provides an incorrect *id*, they should be transferred to an error page inside of the child outlet.

So these are my routes:

```
const routes = [{ path: 'record/:type',
                  component: RecordComponent,
                  data: { animation: 'recordPage', },
                  children: [{ path: 'edit/:id', component: RecordEditorComponent },
                             { path: 'error/:code', component: ErrorComponent },
                             /*{ path: '**', redirectTo: 'error/404' }*/] },
                { path: 'error/:code', component: ErrorComponent, data: { animation: 'errorPage' } },
                { path: '**', redirectTo: 'error/404' }];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { paramsInheritanceStrategy: 'always' })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

The first issue I have is the wild card in the child route. If I comment it in, the parent route will not work anymore and I will immediately be redirected to the error page of the child component. However, it obviously should only redirect **if** something else is following the parent route, i.e. `/record/areas/x`, not on `/record/areas` alone. How can I set up the route so it will only trigger on parent route + anything else?

I also have an issue with redirecting along the child route from within my child component. In my RecordEditorComponent's constructor I'm grabbing the arguments for `:type` and `:id` and check if the type is of an enum, as well as whether the id's format is correct (I'm using mongoDb so it must be a 24-character hexadecimal string) and then redirect to the child's error page if any of them is improper. I also redirect to the error page if the database can't find the entry despite a proper url.

```
constructor(private _route: ActivatedRoute, private _router: Router, private _recordService: RecordService) {
  this._paramSubscription = this._route.paramMap.subscribe((parameters: ParamMap) => this.init(parameters));
}

private init(parameters: ParamMap): void {
  let recordType: string | null = parameters.get('type');
  let recordId: string | null = parameters.get('id');

  if (!recordType ||
      !Object.values(RecordType).some((enumValue: string) => enumValue === recordType?.toLowerCase()) ||
      !recordId ||
      !/^[0-9a-f]{24}$/.test(recordId)) {
    this._router.navigate(['/error', 404], { relativeTo: this._route });
    return;
  }

  this._recordService.read(recordType as RecordType, recordId!)
                     .then((value: Record | undefined) => {
                             if (!value) { this._router.navigate(['/error', '404.1'],
                                                                 { relativeTo: this._route });
                                           return; }
                             this.record = value;
                           })
                     .catch((reason: string) => this._router.navigate(['/error', reason],
                                                                      { relativeTo: this._route }));
}
```

The navigation to `/error` at this point will not navigate me to the error page on the child route, but rather to the error page of the parent route, which is not what I want. I have confirmed that `this._route` is indeed the child route (also it would not contain the id parameter in the first place otherwise), yet it seems the `relativeTo` is ignored. How can I navigate to the child's error page?

Please note, the route itself works. If I enter /record/areas/error/500.0, it will properly show the child's error page with the correct error message. Just the redirection from within the component using the angular Router doesn't.